# In a closed, working test network, how would I generate a signed block that a Bitcoin miner would otherwise create?

Tags: mining-reward, miner-configuration, proof-of-work, cpu-mining, nbitcoin

I have a POC where the essential, critical, priority goal is to use C# and the .NET Core Framework (Bouncy Castle for crypto, or Microsoft primitives for BigInteger ) where I do the following

- Accept a number of transactions that include zero or some fee attached to the transactions (P2P pending Tx queue)
- Calculate the relevant block reward and send it to an address as defined in the block specification format
- Calculate the block's Proof of Work value as specified in the Target or other similar value (difficulty)
- Finally submit the following, as calculated by NBitcoin, into the REST API in the full Bitcoin RPC client (isolated test network)

Any assistance in linking NBitcoin to a "software-CPU miner" just as if Bitcoin was invented originally in 2009 would be greatly useful for the prosocial endeavors I'm currently engaged for.

Comment: I will add a bounty of SO points and relevant other gratitude if this works.

Comment: It's hard to help without knowing where you're stuck. You could first look at the mining pseudocode and implement it without any regard to performance, and once it's working, copy-paste SIMD mining code.